# Jquery Datatable - get information on other pages that are not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable, datatables

I am using an HTML table where I have a column of checkboxes, each having assigned a unique ID (checkbox_7, checkbox_8). I used jquery datatables to store the information from html and allowed pagination in the table and also the search function.

I have a javascript function which alerts how many checkboxes are checked:

```
function check_fields_step2()
    {   
        max_students = parseInt(document.getElementById("nr_rows").value);
        selected = 0;

        for(var i=1; i<max_students; i++)
        {
            if(document.getElementById("checkbox_"+i).checked)
            {
                selected++;
            }
        }

        if(selected == 0)
        {
            alert("Choose at least 1 student to proceed to next step");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

However if my checkboxes are on another page, or I use the search function, which both hide some rows, my function cannot find those rows and implicitly the checkboxes.

What is the proper way to check if the checkboxes are checked and still use pagination and search?
(I know I can disable pagination and search and have the whole table on the page, and everything is visible and the function works)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DOM, iterate $(yourtable).DataTable().rows().